# How do I hide a specific div class inside <style>?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on this web page: http://www.teamlally.com/test.php and I'm trying to hide the island chain you see on the right. "class="hawaii-map"

```
<style>
#feature {
display:none;
}
.copyright {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
p {
color: #807C78;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
</style>
```

I can hide the piece of the page using the following, but I'm only trying to hide the island chain. Also when I apply #hawaii-map as the class, nothing happens.

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also when I apply #hawaii-map as the class, nothing happens.

If 'hawaii-map' is the class, try using:

```
.hawaii-map { display: none; }
```

The '#' is for if it's `id='hawaii-map`, not class.